# Multi update products quantities using one soap api request

Tags: magento-1.9, product, api, soap

I tried below code works for single product quantity update in one soap api request but I want to update multi products stock quantities using only one request.

I tried multiple `sku` in array but not work

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');    
 $session = $client->login('xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
echo "<pre>";
$sku = 'product1';
$stockItemData = array(
    'qty' => '22'
);

$result = $client->call(
    $session,
    'product_stock.update',
    array(
        $sku,
        $stockItemData
    )
);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**finally I found a solution**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');    
$session = $client->login('xxxx', 'xxxxx');

 // $productInfo is array which contains all product sku and its quantities which will update to another server 

 $productInfo = array( 
                array('sku'=>'sku1','qty'=>'50000'),
                array('sku'=>'sku2','qty'=>'110'),
                );

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($productInfo as $product )
{
    $calls[] = array('product_stock.update', array($product['sku'], array('qty'=>$product['qty'])));
}

  /* 2 products will go in one request to another server for product   update   stock data(in my case quantities) using SOAP API multiCall method 
 IF YOU HAVE LOTS OF PRODUCT FOR UPDATE TO ANOTHER SERVER THEN YOU CAN REPLACE VALUE IN array_chunk function(in my case 2) 2 is total products data
   */

 foreach(array_chunk($calls, 2) as $skuChunk)
  {
     $result = $client->multiCall($session, $skuChunk);
  }
  echo $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start; // How many times will be elapsed for this operation
```

Comment: Hi @niraj patel please find the link: i have a task like this,  please help me if you know: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/232375/49102