# Magento1.9 inventory updates api

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, inventory

I have a fields in inventory section qty, like below scree shot, i wants to update the qty fields both at a time using magento1.9 soap apis,

[image]

In the above screen shot i wants to update Main and Wholesale quantities at a time using soap api in magento1.9.

The values are saving in below table (`cataloginventory_stock_item`) like:

[image]

Please help me if anyone know.

For single product update I have passed like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento1936/api/soap/?wsdl=1', array('exceptions' => 0));
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test','newapi');
$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,5928);

$productId = '5928';
$stockItemData = array(
    'qty' => '130',
);

$result = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    'product_stock.update',
    array(
        $productId,
        $stockItemData
    )
);

var_dump($result);
```

Thanks

Comment: For all products or single product?

Comment: present for only singlr product

Comment: for single field update i have pass like this :

Comment: find the update question